Chinese Chat meetings transcripts
What are the chinese chat meetings available on this site? Where are the transcripts and where is it possible to read about future meetings?

Funny to see this question being bumped by the Community User. I've never seen anyone in this site's chat room :-/

Chinese Site Meetings List

Note: These meetings will be exclusively focused on the "Meta" part of the site: administration, site strategies and statistics, how to improve the site, how to bring visits, etc.
Official Discussion for the Next Meeting


#1 Chinese Site Meeting (June 16th 2012)


Chinese Language Meetings List

Note: These meetings will be just simple gatherings for people who want to discuss a certain topic about the Chinese language.
Official Discussion for the Next Meeting

